# Converting a selection of a list of objects to an array while the list is being modified

Tags: c#, android, arrays, list, xamarin

I'm collecting phone sensor data and stuffing it into a list of objects starting with a specific class for each sensor thusly:

```
    public class accbuff
    {
        public double ax { get; set; }
        public double ay { get; set; }
        public double az { get; set; }
        public long acct { get; set; }
    }
```

I then append each new sensor reading event (e.Values) and a timestamp to the list thusly:

```
                accList.Add(new accbuff
                {
                    ax = e.Values[0],
                    ay = e.Values[1],
                    az = e.Values[2],
                    acct = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
                });
```

Finally, after a set period of time I want to pass the list contents to some scientific computing method I have, then clear the list and reset the timer.

This is where I need help. I have no problem clearing the list or resetting my timer, but I can't copy the data from the list because while enumerating the copy to an array, a new sensor reading modifies the list.

Sensor readings happen at about 500hz. If I try something like the below I get the enumeration error due to modification.

```
 long[] at = accList.Select(x => x.acct).ToArray();
 stopwatch.Restart();
 accList.Clear();
```

I know I can lock it, but I don't actually want to have a gap in sensor readings while I copy the list to an array for further use. Any strategy to proceed would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate copy of your `List` before selecting properties while the list is updating:

```
var listCopy = accList.ToList();
```

Then use `listCopy`:

```
long[] at = listCopy.Select(x => x.acct).ToArray();
stopwatch.Restart();
accList.Clear();
```

You can also shortcut the whole thing:

```
long[] at = accList.ToList().Select(x => x.acct).ToArray();
stopwatch.Restart();
accList.Clear();
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps:

```
long[] at = accList.ToList().Select(x => x.acct).ToArray();
stopwatch.Restart();
accList.Clear();
```